# How I can write a html code (templete) to a html file by php?

Tags: php, html, fopen, fwrite, fclose

How I can write html code (not executable) to a file by using php `filesystems`. For example I want to put my html page template which includes `DOCTYPE`, `HEADER`, `BODY BLOCK`, `FOOTER` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as i got you question

save file `index.php` instead off `index.html`.

inside you can use

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

when ever you need to write a php(inside body)

use

```
<?php
//php code goes here
?>
```

example

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
//php code goes here
?>
</body>
</html>
```

`php` will work when file extension is `.php`. if file extension is `.html` browser will not recognize your `PHP code` and it shows complete code on browser

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

[Your first PHP-enabled page](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php)

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info)